# Why doesn't the border also surround the embedded video?

Tags: html, css, border

I'm trying to create a border which encompasses a couple of paragraphs and a video in between the paragraphs.  However, when I create a class for the paragraph tag and use CSS to create the border, the border only surrounds the beginning part of the paragraph and not the video and anything afterwards.

Here's the HTML code that I used:

```
<p class = "mechanics_border">
    <a id = "red_wolf">x45 Boss Split (Red Wolf Spawns)</a><br>
    This is paragraph 1.<br>
    <center>
        <video width = "520" height = "340" autoplay muted controls>
            <source src = "videos/valtan/red-wolf-spawns.mp4" type = "video/mp4">
        </video>
    </center>
    <br>
    This is paragraph 2, it's not supposed to have it's own paragraph as I want it to be within the same border.
</p>
```

Here's the CSS code that I wrote for it.

```
.mechanics_border{
    border-style: solid;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: you only use the `border-style` property in your CSS, the border will not be visible because the border-style property specifies the style of the border, but does not define its width or color. try to add  `border-width`

Comment: The `<center>` tag closes the p element, so the p element doesn't wrap the video or paragraph 2. In any case, the center element has been deprecated for decades. Use a span element and CSS to horizontally centre the video instead.